# How to pass value in xmltable

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

How can I pass a variable value inside the xpath of xmltable?

```
DECLARE
  v NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM xml_billrun_files t ,
    xmltable('/invoice/AR_ITEMS[@elem='||v||']/ITEMS/USAGE_RECORDS/SESSION_INFO' 
              passing t.update_xmldoc 
              columns chrg_duration VARCHAR2(20) path 'DURATION', 
                      amount NUMBER path 'AMOUNT') x;
END;
```

I've tried this one.

```
DECLARE
  v NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM xml_billrun_files t ,
    xmltable('/invoice/AR_ITEMS[@elem=$i]/ITEMS/USAGE_RECORDS/SESSION_INFO' 
              passing t.update_xmldoc, xmltype(v) as "i"
              columns chrg_duration VARCHAR2(20) path 'DURATION', 
                      amount NUMBER path 'AMOUNT') x;
END;
```

But it returns an error:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of '0'
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 310
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at line 5
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35648064/266304) to your previous question, I incorrectly used `xmltype(lp) as "lp"` for your XMLQuery call. Not sure why it didn't complain there, but it didn't actually restrict the match anyway...

For this XMLTable call you can pass the number directly, without conversion/cast, as it's already a number:

```
  SELECT chrg_duration, amount
  into ...
  FROM xml_billrun_files t ,
    xmltable('/invoice/AR_ITEMS[@elem=$i]/ITEMS/USAGE_RECORDS/SESSION_INFO' 
              passing t.update_xmldoc, v as "i"
              columns chrg_duration VARCHAR2(20) path 'DURATION', 
                      amount NUMBER path 'AMOUNT') x;
```

If you're doing it in a for loop, then the index is the wrong data type, and you need to cast it to number:

```
  SELECT chrg_duration, amount
  into ...
  FROM xml_billrun_files t ,
    xmltable('/invoice/AR_ITEMS[@elem=$i]/ITEMS/USAGE_RECORDS/SESSION_INFO' 
              passing t.update_xmldoc, cast(v as number) as "i"
              columns chrg_duration VARCHAR2(20) path 'DURATION', 
                      amount NUMBER path 'AMOUNT') x;
```

Comment: but in doing that, with FOR loop, ill get the error `Error(674,46): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NATIVE INTEGER`

Comment: @NelzKi - yes, the answer to the previous question was wrong, I've corrected both. You need to cast the loop variable to a SQL number type.